# Redirect with htaccess on apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to create a virtualhost and allow a htaccess to redirect (it is for a laravel project).
I am my environment is: ubuntu16.04 apache2.4.18 php7.0.4

And here is my /etc/apache2/sites-available/sub.domain.com.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName eatec.es
    ServerAlias webs.eatec.es

    ServerAdmin eloy@eatec.es
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/sub.domain.com/public
    <Directory "/var/html/sub.domain.com/public">
            Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
            AllowOverride All
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
    </Directory>
    #ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    #CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

</VirtualHost>
```

Things that I tried (and remember).
 1. The line of Directory I tried removing the quotes.
 2. The line of Directory I used too this  (removing the subdomain sub -with and without the quotes-).
 3. I move the Directory block from this file to /etc/apache2/apache2.conf (I paste the last of this type of blocks).
 4. I change the AllowOverride option on the  block (on the apache2.conf -with my Directory block in apache.conf but too on sub.domain.com.conf-).
 5. There was more micro changes, sure... but I don´t remember.

One more thing I tried was **a2enmod rewrite** but it doesn´t work (though I see mod_rewrite on the loaded modules if I make a phpinfo()).

This is my .htaccess content:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
</IfModule>
```

It is the default htaccess file on a laravel project. It is supposed to redirect the index.php on the same folder. My folder structure is the next:
/var/www/html/sub.domain.com-------------> All The Project
/var/www/html/sub.domain.com/public---> htaccess and index.php

Any suggestion?? Thanks.

Comment: @anubhava - it looks like OP has done that, no? Would be the default with Laravel anyway.

Comment: @Eloy - You say you're using Apache 2.4, but you are using old directives from 2.2. Remove the `Order` and `Allow` lines and use this instead: `Require all granted`. Also, Remove `Multiviews` from `Options`.

Comment: @anubhava yes the htacces is on the public folder, thanks

Comment: @MikeRockett thanks for the better sintaxis, but the Order an Allow "directives" work... my fail is in the next comment.

Comment: OH MY GOD!! three hours wasted for a simple word on the route, I have Directory "/var/html/sub.domain.com/public" but I ate a word on the route!! :( This works: Directory "/var/html/www/sub.domain.com/public

Comment: Glad you found the problem. `Require all granted` is the correct way to do it in Apache 2.4. The `Order` and `Allow`/`Deny` directives are now part of a module called `mod_access_compat`, and this module will be removed in a future version. So it's better to use the correct method now.